# Installed files are not executed by Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, executable

I am trying to bring different software under a single umbrella and make a whole one setup using Inno Setup. The software included are .NET framework, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, Windows Installer and Crystal Reports.

The problem which I am facing is in the `[Files]` section. I have defined the function name but none of the function executes when the setup is executed.

```
[Files] 

Source: "D:\Inno Setup\Prerequisites\WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName:"wi.exe"; Check: checkwixp86; AfterInstall: InstallWindowsInstaller
Source: "D:\Inno Setup\Prerequisites\WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName:"wi.exe"; Check: checkwi86; AfterInstall: InstallWindowsInstaller
Source: "D:\Inno Setup\Prerequisites\WindowsInstaller4_5\WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName:"wi.exe"; Check: checkwi64; AfterInstall: InstallWindowsInstaller

Source: "D:\Inno Setup\Prerequisites\dotnetfx35\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName:"dotnetfx35.exe"; Check: Checkdotnet; AfterInstall: InstallFramework;

Source: "D:\Inno Setup\Prerequisites\CrystalReports105\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_5.msi"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName:"cr.exe"; Check: ShouldInstallCR86; AfterInstall: InstallCrystalReports
Source: "D:\Inno Setup\Prerequisites\CrystalReports105\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_5.msi"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName:"cr.exe"; Check: ShouldInstallCR64; AfterInstall: InstallCrystalReports

Source: "D:\Inno Setup\Prerequisites\SQLServer2008R2SP2\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName:"sql.exe"; Check: CheckSQLServer86; AfterInstall: InstallSQLServer
Source: "D:\Inno Setup\Prerequisites\SQLServer2008R2SP2\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName:"sql.exe"; Check: CheckSQLServer64; AfterInstall: InstallSQLServer
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`[Files]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection) only "installs" the files, it does not run them.

For that use [`[Run]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection).